# How to track opened file(s) in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am fairly new to Android Studio. In visual studio, there is a functionality to track opened files. i.e if i have a file named usercontrol.ascx opened in the right pane, then in the left pane, where the source tree is, it will high-light the file in Solution explorer.

Does such functionality exist in Android Studio? I poked around the IDE, and doesn't seem to find it?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Project and File Structure**

**Android project view**

By default, Android Studio displays your project files in the Android project view. This view shows a flattened version of your project's structure that provides quick access to the key source files of Android projects and helps you work with the Gradle-based build system. The Android project view:

Shows the most important source directories at the top level of the module hierarchy.
Groups the build files for all modules in a common folder.
Groups all the manifest files for each module in a common folder.

http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html

Answer (score 5):

You don't have the same options directly. But there are several hotkey which can help you.

> Ctrl + E

It opens list of recently activated files.

> Ctrl + N

Enter class name for fast navigation

> Ctrl + Alt + Left Arrow

To return to previous edit place in the same file or any other file.

Also check out Navigation dropdown menu in AndroidStudio.

Hope it helps! Also check `Anil Meenugu` answer

Answer (score 2):

[image]

there is ... look for cross-air like button on left tree pane click on it ... it will highlight currently opened file

Answer (score 2):

To track your opened file, you could use <kbd>ALT + F1</kbd> shorcut to display **Select target** popup and press <kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> for "Project View".

[image]